# Meteor jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, meteor, nitrousio

Today, I was running my app and changing some content in some of my JS files, when all my app started to crash.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery.js:5896
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined ui.js?9419ac08328918a04e7a49464a988d45f851e1b0:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined templating.js?b36d51fd34724d5d501d8557cd9f846874d95aef:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Template' of undefined accounts-ui-unstyled.js?4567e3da09d5e81789340f9ce7ba9dfd4ca855bc:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined spacebars.js?8988006be5c29dbe17997e9691a21dce4e537665:24
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined global-imports.js?79bee564663b0a7d926070d647eb2976c3c4ac58:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.sales-course-landing.js?0a2386fe2d3b6fe1d89e61c5b5e4c116a486a633:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.sales-course-qa001.js?23a3355cccc743773f1a8daf300a90359b14d462:2
```

...and the errors go on...
The weird thing is... the line number in the "**Unexpected end of input jquery.js:5896**" error keeps changing (5896, 4685, etc). And sometimes it references jquery-ui as well.
And sometimes my app loads normally, just by (F5) refreshing the browser.
I've heard the jquery issue may not be the initial error, even if it is the first in the console order. 


I've reinstalled all packages and meteor updates, and nothing seems to work.
In the deploy to Modulus.IO there is no problem or error.
In my Nitrous console no error is shown.

Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Ok, here is what the amazing Nitrous.IO staff answered me:
 (and I mean it because this was HARD as it gets to narrow down and solve)**

Greg McKeever
9:22 PM - 
So we updated our meteor package and installed it from scratch on your box. Still getting the error :/
After removing the old configs, installing the latest version of meteor, and restarting the box, it looks like that is what was needed.

**Thanks for all attention guys here and in Nitrous.IO!**

Comment: So did you get it fixed? I'm facing the same problems now.

Comment: Yep, Nitrous staff took care for me.
It was an error in their istallations.